# Calendar setup doesn't work

Tags: javascript, calendar

Calendar.setup doesn't work and calendar control doesn't populate on click.

```
  ===This is code in aspx file
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
@import "includes/ui.all.css";
@import  "includes/calendar-win2k-1.css";
@import  "includes/style.css";
   </style>
===
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery-ui-1.8.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/lang/calendar-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/calendar_stripped.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/calendar-setup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/calendar_stripped.js"></script>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    Calendar.setup({
        inputField: "<%=search_start_date.ClientID%>",     // id of the input field
        ifFormat: "%m/%d/%Y",      // format of the input field
        button: "calendar_start_date",  // trigger for the calendar (button ID)
        align: "bR",           // alignment (defaults to "Bl")
        singleClick: true
    });
 </script>

      <asp:TextBox Runat="server" ID="search_start_date" CssClass="TextBox"                 Columns="15" MaxLength="10" />

     <img src="Images/SmallCalendar.gif" border="0"     onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" onmouseout="this.style.cursor='default'"  id="calendar_start_date" alt="Pick Date" />
```

So the problem is when I click on image button it doesn't pop up. I think I have included all required scripts and stylesheets. Can anybody know if I am missing anything here?